# Correct terminology for $P1;P2$?

Tags: turing-machines, terminology, loops

This question is about the correct terminology. Let $P1$ and $P2$ be two LOOP programs. Then $P1;P2$ is also a LOOP program, which executes $P1$ and then executes $P2$. Would this be called concatenation of LOOP programs or nested LOOP programs?

I know the answer has to be concatenation because nested would mean having a LOOP program inside another LOOP program. This is not the same as what is written above. Therefore, the answer has to be the former. I just wanted to make sure that concatenation is the correct term here or is there another, more proper term?

Comment: One name for this operation is *sequential composition*.